# Как добавить байты в определенную позицию файла

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл, в который мне надо добавить последовательность байт. Но не с заменой, а именно добавить.

Подскажите как это сделать?

Использовал этот код для выделения байт и потом перезаписывал выделенные байты. Как-то криво работает.

```
public void ExpandFile(FileStream stream, long offset, int extraBytes)
{
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    var buffer = new byte[SIZE];
    var length = stream.Length;
    stream.SetLength(length + extraBytes);
    var pos = length;
    int to_read;
    while (pos > offset)
    {
        to_read = pos - SIZE >= offset ? SIZE : (int)(pos - offset);
        pos -= to_read;
        stream.Position = pos;
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, to_read);
        stream.Position = pos + extraBytes;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, to_read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вставить в середину файла нельзя, придется прочитать все данные до конца и перезаписать их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считать во временный буфер байты от позиции записи до конца файла, затем вернуться в позицию записи и записать добавляемые байты, а после них записать байты из буфера:

```
public void ExpandFile(FileStream stream, long offset, int extraBytes) {
  byte[] temp = new byte[stream.Length - offset]; 
  stream.Position = offset;  
  stream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
  stream.Position = offset;
  stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(extraBytes), 0, 4);
  stream.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);
}
```